# Using Ratio Keylines in xml

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to align my layouts as shown in the Metrics and Keylines webpage for Material Design,

http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-and-keylines.html#metrics-and-keylines-ratio-keylines

Having trouble figuring out how to apply this to my layouts, how can I do this in xml? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an image to use with the desired aspect ratio (or one is not needed), you could use a placeholder. For instance, I created a shape drawable with dimensions 16px by 9px and used it to adjust the bounds of a relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ratio16x9"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ratio16x9.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <size android:width="16px" android:height="9px"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: What's this got to do with keylines? He didn't say anything about images or aspect ratio.